# How to refactor so many conditionals statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, refactoring

I've a class to compare the imported data with the database values. I ended up with so much conditions that rubocop was shouting loud for it. So I broke the method into smaller methods but there are still conditionals in those methods. Here is the code:

**Before**

```
class Utility
  attr_reader :im_data, :db_data
  def initialize(im_data, db_data)
    @im_data = im_data
    @db_data = db_data
    @to_update = []
    @to_delete = []
  end

  def compare_values
    if !im_data[:name].present?
      @to_delete << im_data[:name]
    elsif im_data[:name].present?
      if im_data[:lookup].present? && (im_data[:lookup] != db_data.full_name)
        @to_update << { id: im_data[:l_v_id], full_name: im_data[:lookup] }
      elsif !im_data[:lookup].present? && (im_data[:name] != db_data.full_name)
        @to_update << { id: im_data[:l_v_id], full_name: im_data[:name] }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**After**

```
def compare_values(im_data, db_data)
  deselection(im_data)
  re_apply(im_data, db_data)
end

def presence?(value)
  value.present?
end

def deselection(im_data)
  @to_delete << im_data[:l_v_id] unless presence?(im_data[:name])
end

def re_apply(im_data, db_data)
  fv_present = presence?(im_data[:name])
  compare_lookup(im_data, db_data.full_name) if fv_present
  compare_name(im_data, db_data.full_name) if fv_present
end

def compare_lookup(im_data, l_value)
  @to_update << { id: im_data[:l_v_id], full_name: im_data[:lookup] } if presence?(im_data[:lookup]) && (im_data[:lookup] != l_value)
end

def compare_name(im_data, full_name)
  @to_update << { id: im_data[:l_v_id], full_name: im_data[:name] } if !presence?(im_data[:lookup]) && (im_data[:name] != full_name)
end
```

I tried to follow this [blog](http://designisrefactoring.com/2015/03/09/refactoring-away-a-conditional/) but no luck with it. I still feel there is a much much better way to refactor this code.

Comment: What can you assume about the incoming `im_data`? Do you really need all those `present?` calls to mash `''`, `nil`, etc. together or can you just say `if im_data.has_key?(:name)` or `if im_data[:name]` instead? Will `db_data.full_name` ever be `nil`? BTW, [`Object#presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) is a useful if this is really Rails.

Comment: `im_data` is an array of hashes. I really need those `present?` calls because `im_data` is an imported data from an `excel sheet`. So the value of it is always like this `''`. `db_data.full_name` can never be `nil`. If it would have been nil then it won't be here in the imported data. Yes, this is used in rails in a `service class`.

Comment: what's wrong with your refactor? By the way there's a code review network as well.

Comment: One suggestion, instead of `!present?`, why not use `blank?`

Comment: But `nil.presence == nil` and `''.presence == nil` too. In general, if `!x.presence?` then `x.presence == nil`, otherwise `x.presence == x`. So you can use `presence` calls to hide conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find "after" much harder to follow. How about the following?

```
def compare_values
  if @im_data[:name].present?
    to_upd(@im_data[:lookup].present? ? :lookup : :name)
  else
    @to_delete << @im_data[:name]
  end
end

def to_upd(key)
  @to_update << { id: @im_data[:l_v_id], full_name: @im_data[key] } unless
    @im_data[key] == @db_data.full_name
end
```

Comment: I agree with your solution but this feature is most likely to change in the future. With your solution, I still feel it would be difficult to make changes here. For example, if `lookup` is present then `compare` two other attributes as well.

Comment: I simply answered your question, which said nothing about accommodating possible future changes in requirements.